# In Android, is it possible to capture screenshots from service

Tags: java, android, screenshot

I'm developing an Android application to capture screenshots. What I'm trying to do is make a service with a button on the top of the screen and taking screenshot by tapping it.

I wonder if it may work, with service as I said. Also I want the button excluded from the screenshot. Am I able to do this?

Answer (score -3):

Here is the code that allowed my screenshot to be stored on sd card and used later for whatever your needs are:

First, add proper permission to save file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

And this is the code (running in an Activity):

```
private void takeScreenshot() {
    Date now = new Date();
    android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);

    try {
        // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
        String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".jpg";

        // create bitmap screen capture
        View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        File imageFile = new File(mPath);

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        int quality = 100;
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

        openScreenshot(imageFile);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        // Several error may come out with file handling or OOM
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And this is how you can open the recently generated image:

```
private void openScreenshot(File imageFile) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

to exclude the button, you can make button hide and then take screen show after some time interval.