# Get alpha value of statusbar

Tags: android, android-styles

On Android I can set a transparent statusbar with the following style line:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

I would like to display a text directly under the statusbar with the same background color of the statusbar. My problem is if I set the background color to my `primaryColor` it is a bit brighter because I haven't added the alpha value of the statusbar to the color.

So how can I get the alpha value of the statusbar from code to add it to my background color?

Comment: Did You see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28041425/6950238) question?

Comment: Thanks for this answer but it's not what I'm looking for.I would like to display a View below the statusbar (to create an extended effect) with the sane alpha value and do not want to Draw behind it.

Comment: Did You try get screenshot like in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35150398/6950238) question and get alpha value for pixel corresponding to StatusBar like in [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645607/android-check-alpha-of-pixel)?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want like this ?

[image]

If yes. After Android 5.0. 
You should set colorPrimaryDark same as colorPrimary. 
colorPrimaryDark means status bar color.
And one important step, if your layout code like this:

```
   <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Delete "AppBarLayout". Change to :

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

Answer (score 0):

On Activity, try get this
`window.statusBarColor`

Comment: The color is not the same as alpha value. Alpha indicates how opaque each pixel is.

Comment: You can get alpha value using Color.alpha() method.
`Color.alpha(window.statusBarColor)`